# How to introduce Simplemembership to an existing MVC 4 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, simplemembership

I know the question looks very broad.
Basically I have an existing MVC 4 application which I based around the tutorial found in the ebook
Pro ASP.NET MVC 4, 4th Edition.
I am working with an existing database, which for now only has one table.
I want to introduce functionality to allow for user's to register and log-in.
As I understand it, this means using Simplemembership (correct?).
But I unclear how to start ? .... will Simplememebership create the required tables automatically ?
If anyone has clear instructions / steps how to start, or a simple yet clear tutorial they know of, I very much appreciate it.
Again please note - this is an ASP.NET MVC 4 Internet Application built using VS 2010 connected to SQL express database, using Razor views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start a new ASP.NET MVC 4 project in Visual Studio 2012 so you can see the default template

Then copy Filters\InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs to your existing application

Thereafter add the attribute [InitializeSimpleMembership] to the AccountController in your existing application

Lastly you can copy the Login, Logoff and Register methods to the AccountController in your exising application

You will also need some settings in your Web.config. Have a look in the Web.config file in the default template. I think these should be enough

```
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcApplication1-20141017110935;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcApplication1-20141017110935.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
</entityFramework>
```

Comment: Yup, I have all the above. the only different, is the version Number is , Version = 6.0.0.0 .... so with all that in place what ? simply start registering users via the UI. ?? (I hit an error when I do that)

Comment: Make sure you also copy AccountModel.cs and include it in your project, as well as the relevant parts of the Login.cshtml and Register.cshtml views.

What error are you seeing?

Comment: I have model and views.... when I click register I get an error in the IntializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs, on line LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref_initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock); .... Inner Exception - {"The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588"} .... next inner expection - {"Keyword not supported: 'file access retry timeout'."}       ..... keep in mind I have no user table ? do I need to manually create ??

Comment: Got it !!! the error was caused by the name in my connection string . thanks all.

Comment: I tried to follow this procedure but my existing tables all got deleted. What just happened? All there is in the database are the tables related to authentication.